# Secondary "Management" NIC on SBS 2011?

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, nic

Looking for a solution to an issue I've run into at a site.  Essentially we've run out of network drops for a server.  The server itself has all of the necessary network drops, but we do not have one for the new UPS.  I'm trying to get the UPS to be seen by both the virtual host and SBS hyper V guest that's running on it.  This will require a secondary NIC to be added to SBS 2011.

Looking into this, I see that two NICs wasn't supported in SBS2008:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2008/09/16/sbs-2008-supported-networking-topology.aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2010/02/26/returning-small-business-server-2008-to-a-supported-network-topology.aspx

So, there's that.  With that said, most of the issues caused by dual NICs seem to be with same subnet, or trying to route between NICs.  Also, it's on SBS 2008.  In my case, the second NIC will only be used for the UPS signals.  Beyond the shutdown command, no other traffic will go over it.

Has anyone tried something similar?  Terrible idea?

Let me know what you think.  Thanks,

Comment: As it is a Windows Server underneath, SBS 2011 will *run* with multiple NICs. As will 2008. You might experience trouble with the network connection wizards, though, and risk your support status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $20 5 port unmanaged switch won't be pretty, but it's easier than mucking around with SBS.

Comment: Pretty much what we went with.